# Understanding this character database format

Tags: database, image-processing, dataset, ocr

For the purpose of doing a project on character recognition, I found a database I could use as a training set. On the other hand, I am not able to understand the given format even though the below instructions were given with it. I could find no further help on how to figure this format out.

Fields 1-6 are separated by commas.

---

1. ID number of source article
2. 2-byte symbol code (written in hexadecimal, using 4 bytes)
3. Character height of bitmap
4. Character width of bitmap
5. Bitmap image, where each 8-bit unit is written as a decimal from 0 to 255
6. Line feed

The link to the file(Google drive) for the database is attached below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-WsCQkhd_1iUUtJdHg0R1hfTHM/view?usp=sharing

It would be of great help if someone could figure out the way this format is presented. It is literally puzzling me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can understand this format every char description takes one line (until line feed sign).

1. ID number of source article
2. byte symbol code (written in hexadecimal, using 4 bytes)
3. Character height of bitmap
4. Character width of bitmap
5. Bitmap image, where each 8-bit unit is written as a decimal from 0 to 255  - and here the magic starts. Bitmap image is not only one comma separated value, but all values until you meet line feed. So it will be a lot of comma separated values that you can divide in rows using bitmap height and width values.

If you open this file in for example Notepad++ instead of stanart windows notepad, you will get a bit better view (turn on "Show all characters" to see line feed).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I still can't breakdown which columns are for what... like which column for height, which one for width, which for symbol code, etc.

Comment: 1 column must be an id. 2-3 may be a 2-symbol code 1 byte per column, 3 - height, 4 - width, next columns i can't understand, but self bitmap data probably starts from column 15, at least all values after this column in range from 0 to 255, every bit in each value represent one pixel (probably) , what is purpose of columns 5-14 I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, and for height an width, you meant 4th and 5th column right.

Comment: Basically I need to know the height, width and character code of the image. Thanks for your help.